# Tao's motivation for replacement axiom

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, axioms

In Tao's Analyis I, one motivation for introducing the axiom of replacement is that one cannot obtain the set $\{4,6,10\}$ from $\{3,5,9\}$. While I intuitively understand this, is there a somewhat rigourous proof to show that the above cannot be achieved using the axioms introduced so far in his book: extensionality, empty set, pair set, pairwise union, specification (and perhaps axiom of infinity to make sense of the given sets)?

I include a snapshot of quoted example:

[image]

Comment: This particular example does not actually require Replacement (you can prove it exists using the other axioms).  In fact, probably nothing in that entire book really requires Replacement.

Comment: @EricWofsey So if I understand correctly: axiom of specification (rather than replacement) is enough to carry out most of the mathematics in his book. Also, I have seen a lot of discussion on the fact that replacement (plus empty set) implies specification. Am I right in saying that the converse is not true?

Comment: That's correct: replacement is strictly stronger than specification (in the presence of the other axioms).